# Issue with the sound volumes in button press:

Tags: android, onclick, android-audiomanager

I'm developing currently an IME, and I have sound for button click. I have an option in the preferences screen to change the volume of the sounds. The SeekBar values are going from 0.0 to 1.0. Now I try to let the user to configure the volume of the buttons in the preferences screen and later I get this value and save it as `mSoundVol` parameter. So for the sound of the click I wrote the following method:

```
 float soundVolume;
 int maxVolume, sound;

        switch (primaryCode) {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE;
                Log.d(TAG+ "-volume", "chosen sound: mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE");
                break;
            case ASCII_ENTER:
                maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN;
                Log.d(TAG+ "-volume", "chosen sound: mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN");
                break;
            case ASCII_SPACE:
                maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR;
                Log.d(TAG+ "-volume", "chosen sound: mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR");
                break;
            default:
                maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD;
                Log.d(TAG + "-volume", "chosen sound: mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD");
        }

        soundVolume = maxVolume * mSoundVol;
        Log.d(TAG+ "-volume", "current max volume: " + maxVolume + " current volume setting: " +mSoundVol * 100 +"%" + " volume result: " + soundVolume);
        mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(sound, soundVolume);
```

But for some reason this does not change the volume of the sound for the user.

Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong with the AudioManager here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was this:

```
 float soundVolume;
        int maxVolume, sound;

        switch (primaryCode) {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE;
                break;
            case ASCII_ENTER:
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN;
                break;
            case ASCII_SPACE:
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR;
                break;
            default:
                sound = mAudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD;
                break;
        }
        maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundVolume = maxVolume * mSoundVol;
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM , (int)(soundVolume * 1.5) , 0);
        mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(sound);
```

The important thing was to pass `0` as the last parameter of the `setStreamVolume` method, that way this action only changes the volume without playing any other sound of showing the volume UI.

Answer (score 1):

your need to use this method for a more accurate result

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
    (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                             [int value],
                             [if desired a flag]);
```

EDIT

Take this FLAg as example

```
AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND
```

This means that whenever the user press the volume Button a bip will be outputed

EDIT 2

here is an implementation of the code

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                             AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(),
                             AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: what are the flag here for?

Comment: Edited with flag explanation

Comment: I don't understand, if I want to commit the same operation I'm doing with the playSoundEffect method, what should I do?

Comment: Will this still take in affect the different sound for the different buttons (Space, Enter, Delete button, etc...)?

Comment: yes but you need to adjust the snippet to your code for that

Comment: I tried to apply you solution, but this changes the sound of the button clicks and it shows the volume bar each time I press on a button. If you look cearfully I'm using the FX_KEYPRESS constants and not the stream constants. Maybe this could be the reason.

Comment: did you change the AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume() with the desired value ? whenever you presse the button up you need to increase this value to increase the volume

Comment: instead of playing the sound using playSoundEffect method with volume I did this: mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(sound, (int)soundVolume , sound); mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(sound);

Comment: the 3 param should be a Flag like this one AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND

Comment: Yeah you are right. Now it does not show me the volume ui each time I press a button. but the sound are still incorrect. I should use the sound provided by the FX_ constants.